# How to add 1 hour to date('H')

Tags: php, date

Simple question, how to add 1 hour to

```
$time = date('H');
```

I have seen some examples, but havent managed to make it work with date('H')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my suggestion is

```
$time = date('H'); 
echo $time+1;
```

Comment: This will not work if "date('H')" = 23, 23+1 = 24 or you'll have to specify if($time == 24) $time = 0;

Answer (score 5):

Use PHP `strtotime`:-

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+1 hours'));
```

Comment: date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+1 hours')) <- add missing bracket

Comment: thanks  :) - @JamieSterling

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo date("H", strtotime('+1 hours'));
```